# What issues can I expect if I install Windows 11 on unsupported hardware?

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I decided to upgrade to Windows 11 and downloaded Win11_English_x64v1.iso from the [official link](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11), tried to install the OS via `setup.exe`, and here is what happened:

[image]

> This PC doesn't currently meet Windows 11 system requirements
> Here's why:
>
> - The processor isn't supported for this version of Windows.
> - The PC must support TPM 2.0
> - The PC must support Secure Boot

Hardware compositions of the computer I am using:

| Component | Model |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | Intel Core i5-4430 @ 3.00GHz |
| RAM | Kingston 16 GiB DDR3 1600 MHz |
| GPU | NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1050 Ti |
| Mainboard | BIOSTAR H81MHV3 |
| Storage | multiple devices 5587.94 GiB |

I checked the [official list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-11-supported-intel-processors) of supported CPUs and my CPU is not listed.

TPM 2.0 stands for [Trusted Platform Module 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) and according to [this](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/motherboards-that-support-tpm-windows-11/), my motherboard doesn't have it.

Double checked with device manager, there is no "Security Devices":

[image]

`msinfo32.exe` says Secure Boot is unsupported

[image]

But here is the minimum hardware requirements for Windows 11 according to official [Microsoft specifications](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-specifications):

| Component | Requirement |
| --- | --- |
| Processor | 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with 2 or more cores on a compatible 64-bit processor or System on a Chip (SoC). |
| RAM | 4 gigabyte (GB). |
| Storage | 64 GB or larger storage device Note: See below under “More information on storage space to keep Windows 11 up-to-date” for more details. |
| System firmware | UEFI, Secure Boot capable. Check here for information on how your PC might be able to meet this requirement. |
| TPM | Trusted Platform Module (TPM) version 2.0. Check here for instructions on how your PC might be enabled to meet this requirement. |
| Graphics card | Compatible with DirectX 12 or later with WDDM 2.0 driver. |
| Display | High definition (720p) display that is greater than 9” diagonally, 8 bits per color channel. |

My monitor's resolution is 1920x1080.

According to the minimum requirements, all the hardware components exceed the minimum performance requirements by far, but my hardware is listed as unsupported...

TPM is mostly useless, it is related to Windows Defender and Smart Screen and other bloatware, I have disabled Windows Defender and Smart Screen and other crap that were designed to make your computer "more secure" a long time ago, and all this time without using any and all anti-virus software, for several years, and my computer is fine.

My motherboard does support UEFI and Secure Boot, but enabling them introduces all sorts of problems when setting dual boot with Fedora 34 using EasyBCD, so I disabled them, and I don't want to enable them.

Now obviously I can't install Windows 11 via the installer without tweaking the system.

I am very literate in computers and very experienced in Python and PowerShell, and I have multiple disks, so I can install it using `DISM`

According to this:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> dism /get-imageinfo /imagefile:I:\sources\install.wim

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.844

Details for image : I:\sources\install.wim

Index : 1
Name : Windows 11 Home
Description : Windows 11 Home
Size : 15,918,540,541 bytes

Index : 2
Name : Windows 11 Home N
Description : Windows 11 Home N
Size : 15,229,765,223 bytes

Index : 3
Name : Windows 11 Home Single Language
Description : Windows 11 Home Single Language
Size : 15,921,439,394 bytes

Index : 4
Name : Windows 11 Education
Description : Windows 11 Education
Size : 16,201,186,274 bytes

Index : 5
Name : Windows 11 Education N
Description : Windows 11 Education N
Size : 15,500,722,223 bytes

Index : 6
Name : Windows 11 Pro
Description : Windows 11 Pro
Size : 16,198,033,078 bytes

Index : 7
Name : Windows 11 Pro N
Description : Windows 11 Pro N
Size : 15,515,196,102 bytes

Index : 8
Name : Windows 11 Pro Education
Description : Windows 11 Pro Education
Size : 16,201,137,484 bytes

Index : 9
Name : Windows 11 Pro Education N
Description : Windows 11 Pro Education N
Size : 15,500,672,533 bytes

Index : 10
Name : Windows 11 Pro for Workstations
Description : Windows 11 Pro for Workstations
Size : 16,201,161,879 bytes

Index : 11
Name : Windows 11 Pro N for Workstations
Description : Windows 11 Pro N for Workstations
Size : 15,500,697,378 bytes

The operation completed successfully.
```

I want Windows 11 Pro for Workstations, so all I need to do is:

```
Dism /apply-image /imagefile:I:\Sources\install.wim /index:10 /ApplyDir:F:\
BCDboot F:\Windows /s F: /f ALL
```

But I haven't run it yet, because the only SSD in the computer is the boot drive of the current OS I am using, and installing the OS to HDD means long boot time, so in order to have short boot time I have to wipe the current boot disk and reinstall all the software I am using...

But according to [this](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-11-without-tpm-20-and-why-you-shouldnt), I can use the following tweaks to allow Windows 11 to be installed via `setup.exe`:

```
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" -Name "BypassTPMCheck" -Type "DWord" -Value 0x00000001
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" -Name "BypassRAMCheck" -Type "DWord" -Value 0x00000001
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" -Name "BypassSecureBootCheck" -Type "DWord" -Value 0x00000001
```

But I haven't tested it yet, because if any problems occurs, I have to do a clean install again... Like the fiftieth time...

So before I proceed I need to know exactly what issues I should expect if I install Windows 11 on unsupported hardware, and if installing Windows 11 on this computer is a stupid idea.

I have seen the [official disclaimer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/installing-windows-11-on-devices-that-don-t-meet-minimum-system-requirements-0b2dc4a2-5933-4ad4-9c09-ef0a331518f1), but they don't actually spell out what issues might arise, they only state that your computer will no longer receive updates.

I am not like most users, I am extremely tech-savvy and very competent in programming, but I have never done this before so I want to know what I should expect.

---

None of the reinstalls were due to viruses and the like, they were because of corrupted user profiles caused by blackouts which happens rather frequently in my locale, and I don't use BitLocker, Windows Hello and biometrics and all other fancy security features, I hate them and disabled all of them.

Comment: Potentially having no updates or having to do feature updates manually. Its not worth fighting until Windows 10 is properly out of support in 2025 or if you specifically need Win11 features.

Comment: At this point in space and time Windows 10 is better than 11. Why downgrade?

Comment: Secure Boot is unsupported because you installed Windows in Legacy mode. Windows 11 doesn’t support Legacy Mode at all. There is no way around that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 11 Production will not install cleanly on unsupported hardware.

You can do two things:

(1) Join the Windows Insider Program (Start, Settings, Updates) and then Windows 11 Insider will normally install.

(2) Make a registry change to run Windows 11 in an unsupported manner.

[Run Windows 11 unsupported](https://windowsreport.com/install-windows-11-on-unsupported-processor/)

Use Regedit to navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\MoSetup
```

In the right pane, you can right-click and select New and then select the DWORD (32-bit) Value.

Once the value is created, you can rename it to :

```
AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU.
```

You can now double click on this new value and enter 1 into the Value data field. Hit OK and close the registry editor.

Close out, restart, download the Windows 11 ISO and install it.

This process will make the 3 partitions you need, so make sure your system is backed up.

**Watch for:**

(A) You may not get updates at some point.

**Note:**  I am seeing that an older Insider machine (2013) is not as far up to date (221xxx) as a later machine (2016) (25151).  So how far you get updates depends on your machine.

(B) Vendors are not providing a lot of support (specifically driver support) for older, unsupported hardware.

I have two Insider machines and on the best of the two, my dual band wireless card only works on 2.4GHz with Windows 11 and the Fingerprint reader does not work properly. No help from Lenovo on this.

Is it worth it for you?  Only you can answer that.

I have two new machines (Desktop and Laptop) running Windows 11 Pro and Windows 11 generally works fine. It is very different from Windows 10 and I have adapted to Windows 11 (and not tried to turn it into Windows 11).

Comment: The author can just use Rufus and avoid all your steps with a simple checkbox. Of course the fact they are currently running in Legacy Mode is an blocker without a solution unless they use MBR2GPT to go to UEFI before the upgrade but they have indicated that’s not an option they are willing to do.